# Add Min Row in R

Tags: r, min

I have read a lot of similar questions, but cannot get any of the code to work. I simply want to add a row to the bottom of my data frame (df) that has the min value for each column for columns 2:8. Below is my code (that works) to add a total line, but I want a min line.

```
df[(nrow(df)+ 1),(2:8)] <- colSums(df[,2:8], na.rm=TRUE)
```

I have tried to get colMins in package matrixStats to work, but can't for some reason. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try `colMins` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
rbind(df, c(NA,colMins(as.matrix(df[2:8]))))
```

#### Update

To replace `NA` with 'MIN',

```
rbind(df, c('MIN',as.list(colMins(as.matrix(df[2:8])))))
```

Or another approach would be to convert to `matrix` and use `addmargins`

```
addmargins(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df[-1]), df$ID), 1, FUN=min)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- cbind(ID= 1:10,as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 7*10, 
   replace=TRUE), ncol=7)))
```

Comment: That looks like it works great! Sorry to add something, how can I add a name (e.g. "MIN" to the row in column 1?) BTW, I did edit for my data set to add `na.rm = TRUE` (e.g. as follows): `df1 <- rbind(df1, c(NA, colMins(as.matrix(df1[2:8]), na.rm = TRUE)))`. I have added a row name before with this code, but for some reason it is not working... `df1[(nrow(df1)),(1)] <- "MIN"`

Comment: I figured out something that worked although I'm not certain it is the most savvy way. I added the following and it works: `df1[, c(1)] <- as.character(df1[, c(1)])` and then on the next line my prior code `df1[nrow(df1)), (1)] <- "MIN"`

Comment: @stevenjoe  Looks like RichardScriven did an update for the comment.  Please check if the modification of that code works for my code.  If not, I will update.

Answer (score 5):

In base R, you can use `sapply()` to create an atomic vector of column minimums and then `rbind()` to attach it to the original data.  I added an `NA` for the first value, since we need something there to add it to the original data.

```
rbind(df, c(NA, sapply(df[2:8], min, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Obviously this assumes only 8 columns, and so `df[-1]` can be used in place of `df[2:8]`.

And for a speed increase we can use `vapply()` over `sapply()` because we know the result will be a single numeric value.

```
rbind(df, c(NA, vapply(df[-1], min, 1, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

**Update:** In response to your comment on the other answer - to get `"MIN"` in the first column and the minimum values in all the rest, we can adjust the call to a named list and do it all in one go.  This way we don't mix the column classes (character and numeric) and end up with unexpected classes in the columns of the resulting data.

```
rbind(
    df, 
    c(setNames(list("MIN"), names(df)[1]), lapply(df[-1], min, na.rm = TRUE))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do it in base and also annotating what the "NA" was for--I didn't know that. Thank you as well Richard.

Comment: Thank you also for the explanation of vapply vs. sapply. Very helpful!

Comment: @stevenjoe - No problem, happy to help. I also added an update that addresses your comment on the other answer